# Direct link for vimeo video

Tags: api, windows-phone, vimeo

I'm developing a Windows Phone App and I want to play Vimeo video in the App. But I have an issue, Windows Phone Apps can't embed player, so player will open in browser. I don't like that it opens external app, I would like that users stay in my app. 
How can I get direct link for playing Vimeo video in my own video player?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I got email from Vimeo support.
Quote:
You’ll need to become a PRO member if you’d like access to static video URLs on both the site and via our API.
Vimeo PRO FAQ: http://bit.ly/18Y8s6f

Comment: Could you paste the relevant section here?

Comment: Yes, please paste the relevant info and make SO a more useful site for everyone.